# SQL select single row with two matching values

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm probably having a bad day, but this is somehow escaping me:

I want to return the second row in this table only.

```
userId    val1    val2
1          11      12
2          13      14
3          13      15 
4          16      17
```

Using `SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1=13 AND val2=14` obviously returns 2 rows, the second and third. Whats the correct way to select ONLY the second row? Where val1 is 13 and val2 is 14?

EDIT: I'm an idiot.

Comment: what you have is correct

Comment: Yeah `SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1=13 AND val2=14` isn't returning the second and the third, but only the second.

Comment: cant see why it returns 2 rows, only 2nd row matches the where clause, third row has val2=15

Comment: It should not return the third row. val2 != 14 on that row.

Comment: Everybody has a bad day - what I am most impressed with is that there were no down votes.

Comment: ha, I think you've just solved that issue @PaulF

Comment: Not me - it has to be really bad for me to down vote a question or answer - just too nice.

Comment: Wasn't me either I'm 4 points short of reputation for the privilege ;-).
I was rather trying to flag it, but there is no flag reason for "questions answers itself".
@OliverJ90 Good luck that nothing more bad happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `SELECT * FROM table WHERE val1=13 AND val2=14`like you already mentioned in your question, because in fact, it actually returns only  row number 2.

Answer (score 1):

If it has been a very bad day & there is a typo in your question & val2 in third row also equals 14 - the only way your query would return two rows, then this would do what you want

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE val1=13 AND val2=14 
ORDER BY userId
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: IMHO you should explain him on which additional criteria he will get only one row.

Comment: I thought LIMIT 1 to be fairly self-explanatory. Now if he wanted the second & I used LIMIT 1,1 then I would have explained about the initial 0 offset.

Comment: @PauF it's not only the LIMIT but also the ordering, which implies in this context "Just get me one matching this criteria and let it be the one with the smallest `userId`".

Answer (score 0):

If you get 2 rows, then there must be 2 rows match the condition.
Maybe you could try:

```
select count(*)
from table
where val1=13 AND val2=14;
```

to show the size of result set.